# Magento2.0.7 reindexing shows proccessing?

Tags: magento2, reindex, magento-2.0.7

i have executed following command 
`sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

it is running  successfully but **magento2 admin panel** it shows **processing**
 suggest any solution

Answer (score 0):

After waiting for a long time still if it's not updated then directly execute following query to your database.

```
UPDATE indexer_state SET status = 'valid';
```

It will solve problem within next second.